# "The number of residents has grown" vs. "the number of residents have grown"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subjects, quantifiers

> 1. The number of residents **has** grown.
>    2. The number of residents **have** grown.

Which of the above sentences is grammatical? Since *has* should stick with singular nouns and *have* with plural ones, I guess (2) should be correct, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Isn't 'residents' the subject here? I have checked the question given above and have almost got my answer cleared but am confused regarding the subject.

Comment: In the book am referring, (1) is given as correct usage, which negates the answer given to the question(A number of questions "has been" or "have been" asked?) you have pointed to.

Comment: How could *residents* be the subject? It is the object of the preposition. The subject is *number*.

Comment: No, the grammatical subject of the sentence is "number"; "residents" is the object of the preposition "of". You can elide the sentence to read: "The number... has grown" but not to "The... residents have grown" because the first means the same as "the number of residents has grown" but the second doesn't. It's all very simple if it's done this way.

Comment: @tchrist: No, this usage of *number* is quite different from that other question; it's not a duplicate. Here *the number* clearly forces the singular, because *residents* cannot grow, that is, it would mean something very different. Conversely, *questions* can be asked.

Comment: @AnujBalan no, your book does not negate the answer to that other question. Read carefully. "'The number' is singular" is the very first thing it says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s singular, *has*, because *number* is the head of the subject phrase. It would be plural if the subject phrase was *a number of residents* in, for example, *A number of residents have complained.* There, *a number of* is a pre-modifying element.